# Image:make(path) Image source not readable when i use artisan custom command

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, intervention

i hope you can help me with my problem.

I have a Laravel application and i wanna optimize all my images.

I use a controller for that, but i have a lot of images, and i get execution_maxim_time_exceed.

I think, the best way to do that is to creat an artisan command.

So, i creat my with `php artisan make:command Name command:example`.

After, I move my code from controller to handle() from artisan command.

I can use `Storage:move($oldPath, $newPath)`, but i can't use `Image:make($filePath).`

My file storage is "`storage/app/images/image.png`" and filePath is '`images/image.png`'

When i use the controller, the method `isFilePath()` from `Intervention\Image\AbstractDecoder` return true, but in artisan command return false.

Method `isFilePath()` call the function `is_file()`

```
    public function isFilePath()
    {
        if (is_string($this->data)) {
            try {
                return is_file($this->data);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Why i get false from the function is_file() with the same path for file in artisan command, and in controller i get true? (for the same path).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i found the solution. 
In the controller is_file('images/image.png') return true, but in the cli, i need to use the full path
so, in CLI i use 'storage/app/images/image.png'.